# convert a binary String containing 64bits to hexadecimal in java?

Tags: java, string, biginteger

I'm trying to convert this binary String that contains 64bits to Hexadecimal with this code:

```
String mm = "1000010111101000000100110101010000001111000010101011010000000101";
String v = new BigInteger(mm, 2).toString(16);
v=String.format("%64x", v);
```

but it gives me this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: x != java.lang.String
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.String.format(Unknown Source)
    at test.main(test.java:332)
```

what is getting wrong and why?

Comment: That looks like a binary string rather than a hex string. Why the 16 in the `BigInteger` constructor? Shouldn't it be 2?

Comment: @JohnColeman Sorry, you are right, I had edit it and forgot to change  when I have post this question. Thank u.

Comment: Your `String.format("%64x", v);` uses a type character of `x` which says to treat the argument `v` as an `unsigned int` and format it in hexadecimal — but your `v` is a String already.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**change this:**

```
v=String.format("%64x", v);
```

**to this:**

```
v=String.format("%s", v);
```

**Also you need this:**

```
String v = new BigInteger(mm, 2).toString(16);
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution – it was great. :)

Comment: This just appends `64x` onto the end of `85e813540f0ab405`